# How to configure pycharm remote interpreter with virtualenv

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

I have a project with a remote interpreter, we recently started using virtualenv.
That change broke my Pycharm debugger because it points to the default python interpreter on the remote machine instead of the virtualenv.

In Pycharm, there is a possibility to use a local virtualenv however, I don't see a way to use virtual env with a remote.

So the question is, is there a way to use virtualenv on a remote server with pycharm? and if so, then how?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to find a workaround, in the remote server I added a source command to the .bashrc into the virtualenv, so every process running ssh and then python will actually run the virtualenv's python, so once Pycharm connects via ssh, its already in the correct virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a late comer to this, but there's an easier way to do this that allows you to target multiple VMs on the remote system (and is also generally useful when doing remote python invocation.)

When you're setting up your remote interpreter in PyCharm, point it to the instance of python interpreter you'd like to use.  By default, it suggests /usr/bin/python2.7 ,  but if you point it the python instance in virtual environment. It will pick up the complete environment for the remote env including libraries, etc.

(e.g. choose /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python if your vm is in /home/ubuntu/venv).

Comment: somehow this doesnt work. Despite I have configured interpreter path as the python bin inside anaconda/envs/myenv/ pycharm keeps executing the regular python bin of anaconda